# How to make a circular grid in geometry nodes?

Tags: texturing, shaders, shader-nodes, geometry-nodes

I was following Blender Guru's latest tutorial of LED in geometry nodes (https://youtu.be/_TYD-CRDGXI). I wanted to get the same results but on a circular grid. [Model Below]

Blender Guru uses a grid in geometry nodes for his tutorial but I just wanted to know how to make that grid bend into a complete circle so that I can use that on my model.

[image: LED Strip]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the point of the tutorial is using text object to control on and off state of the LEDs, I would suggest this setup:

[image]

[image]

In this setup, we use the geonodes setup from blender guru, including the method of turning on and off state using ray cast. Then LEDs were instanced blend them using sin and cos of its original positions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much for this. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't care about external video tutorials.

But I would solve the task as follows:

[image]

Simply use a cylinder that is divided accordingly and keep only the sides of the cylinder.

Split these sides with the node `Split Edges` so that you can scale and extrude the faces individually.

---

Of course you can also use the node `Instance on Points` instead of this technique and instantiate any other objects on the points:

[image]

[image]